# Laravel Custom Collections

Tags: laravel, collections, collect

I'm trying to understand something. Consider the following:

```
$collection = collect(['example1' => 'test1', 'example2' => 'test2']);
```

When I do the following, I end up with this result:

```
Collection {#867 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "example1" => test1
    "example2" => test2
  ]
}
```

What I want to be able to do is this:

```
echo $collection->example1 // Should display test1
```

But instead it says `"Trying to get property of non object"`.

So, I have two questions:

1. Can somebody explain the above behaviour?
2. Can somebody help with a solution so I can do `$collection->example1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections are objects containing an array. If you look back at what you posted you can see that you have an object of class Collection that contains an item which is an array. You can access the array items in normal array syntax or using the object's getter.

```
$product->get('subscription'); //object oriented way
$product['subscription']; //access as an array item
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now, and I will figure out a better solution to my problem :)

Comment: If you can tell me exactly what you are trying to do (eg: why the OOP approach doesn't fit your need) I may can edit my answer with a solution.

Comment: Ah no worries, your answer is perfect. What I am trying to do is, I am using events for something. And I have added the functionality to import a csv now, and while processing the csv imports, I wanted to use the events for that as well, without having to edit the event classes. So I needed to be able to use `$example->test`, exactly like that. Either way I solved my issue another way. But I still learned some stuff from your answer. Thanks again!